# Subtract 8 bits or 8 bytes from the Stack Pointer?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm very new to asm,

does this:

```
sub $0x8, %esp
```

subtract 8 bits or 8 bytes from the stack pointer?

Comment: It subtracts 8 Bytes from the stack

Comment: I'd guess at x86 assembly, but shouldn't have to. Please add an appropriate tag for your processor architecture. There's more than one in the world, and they have different assembly languages (even if they appear superficially similar)

Comment: You don't subtract "bytes" or "bits" from the stack pointer. The stack pointer is a number, and you subtract another **number** from it. And since generally pointers address bytes, not bits, this will make the SP point to 8 bytes off its previous value.

Comment: @H2CO3:  Your discussion is technically correct, but it is useful to think about "units" when doing arithmetic.  In a calculator, your physics units (kg, ergs, ...) aren't visible exactly as "bytes" aren't visible in the stack value subtraction.  But that number in the register *really* is a byte address.  So you are "subtracting (bytes)", IMHO.

Comment: @juicy: I'm surprised at the negative votes.  Your question isn't very deep, but you have the guts to ask it and learn the truth.  I gave you +1 for that reason.

Comment: Yes. And +1 from me too.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it as IA-32 assembly on gnu tool chain, with at&t syntax,
It subtracts 8 **Bytes** from the stack pointer...

That means your stack grows 8 Bytes downwards, allowing you to store more 8 Bytes of data there.

Also refer [H2CO3's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636279/subtract-8-bits-or-8-bytes-from-the-stack-pointer#comment29153825_19636279). It has the correct perspective that you don't subtract bits or bytes, but just a number and as pointers point to a byte, it points 8 bytes below.

Comment: It is worth noting that on the x86 architecture, you should not move the ESP by anything other than a multiple of 4 (for x86-32) or 8 (x86-64).   It may *work* to use other values, but the stack pointer is heavily used to store/fetch temporary values, and having it misaligned with respect to the word architecture of the machine would cause a significant performance hit, if indeed Intel doesn't disallow it altogether.

Comment: Yah... +1 for that... When I write stand alone programs in assembly, I align `%esp` using `andl` instruction... And use `%ebp` for accessing parameters & locals. I usually subtract the required storage(local + arguments) beforehand and use `%esp` for pushing the arguments for called function.